# setvalidator on a FormControl does not make the form invalid

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

HTML code

```
<div>
    <label for=""
      >No additional information flag:</label>
    <rca-checkbox formControlName="noAdditionalInfoCheckbox"  (checkboxChecked)="onCheckboxChecked($event)"></rca-checkbox>
</div>
<div>
    <label >No additional information reasons:</label>
    <textarea
      formControlName="noAdditionalInformationReasons"
      id=""
      class="form-control"
    ></textarea>
</div>
```

TS file

```js
onCheckboxChecked(isChecked): void {
 
  const noAdditionalInfoReasonsControl = this.addNewRequestFormForIndividual.get('noAdditionalInformationReasons');
  if (isChecked){
     
      noAdditionalInfoReasonsControl.setValidators(Validators.required);
      this.noAddInfoReasonsErrorMessage = "give reason";
  }
  else {
     
      
    noAdditionalInfoReasonsControl.clearValidators;
    this.noAddInfoReasonsErrorMessage = '';
  }
    
  noAdditionalInfoReasonsControl.updateValueAndValidity;
    
  console.log(this.addNewRequestFormForIndividual.valid);
  
}
```

If the checkbox is checked, I want to add a required validator to the second `FormControl` and the Add button over the form will be disabled if the form is not valid.

Now what I see is that the last console prints true even if I am setting the validators above and the Add button does not get disabled. Also, I see that when I start making modifications to the field which was made required then the validation state starts to change like I wrote something in the required field and then remove it then the add button gets disabled and the form state becomes invalid.

But then if I even uncheck the checkbox, the form is still invalid. I want to understand why it is happening even when I am using `updateValueAndValidity`.

Answer (score 1):

[`clearValidators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#clearvalidators) and [`updateValueAndValidity`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) are the methods. You miss out the `()` so both methods are not called. Add `()` in order to call the method as below:

```js
noAdditionalInfoReasonsControl.clearValidators();
```

```js
noAdditionalInfoReasonsControl.updateValueAndValidity();
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wildvu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)